# OpenCL, half vs float performance

Tags: c++, c, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I'm currently working on an application that requires large amounts of variables to be stored and processed (~4gb in float)

Since precision of the individual variables are of less importance (I know that they'll be bounded), I saw that I could use OpenCL's half instead of floats, since that would really decrease the amount of memory.

My question is twofold.

- Is there any performance hit to using half instead of float (I'd image graphics cards being built for float operations)
- Is there a performance hit for mixing floats and half's in calculations? (i.e, a float times a half.)

Sincerily,
Andreas Falkenstrøm Mieritz

Comment: I would believe the answer is very hardware dependent. So you should measure and benchmark.

Comment: Definitely benchmark because it's definitely situational. The usual places `half` wins over `float` -- if it does at all -- have to do with memory bandwidth and cache efficiency. Most hardware cannot compute `half` results faster than `float`; they're just faster to move around.

Comment: A rule of thumb is that half wins when transferring memory to GPGPU and loses, when needs to be typecasted in a shader. I don't think that the amount of calculation units is increased when moving from float to half...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ARM CPUs and GPUs have native support for `half` in their ALUs so you'll get close to double speed, plus substantial savings in energy consumption. **Edit:** The same goes for PowerVR GPUs.

Desktop hardware only supports `half` in the load/store and texturing units, AFAIK. Even so, I'd expect `half` textures to perform better than `float` textures or buffers on any GPU. Particularly if you can make some clever use of texture filtering.

Comment: I've started some experiments, and as suggested by several people in here, the memory bandwidth will be the bottleneck, not the calculation speed. As such, using half gives a theoretical 2x speedup. I have yet to try this, but it's the route I'll go.

Thanks for the clarifying answer! Didn't know about the ARM stuff, but it's not too relevant for my current project, but good to know in the future.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCL kernels are almost always memory-speed or pci-speed bound. If you are converting a decent chunk of your data for half floats, this will enable faster transfers of your values. Almost certainly faster on any platform/device.

As far as performance, half is rarely worse than float. I am fairly sure that any device which supports half will do computations as fast as it would with float. Again, even if there is a slight overhead here, you will more than make up for it in your far-superior transfer times.